# [iOS]AVPlayerItemVideoOutput.hasNewPixelBufferForItemTime doesn't work correctly

Tags: ios, iphone, video, avplayer

It's my first question here, so don't be severe.

I'm playing video from the net using AVPlayer. I output the current frame using **AVPlayerItemVideoOutput** attached to the **AVPlayerItem** played by the **AVPlayer**. To check if new frame is ready I call **[AVPlayerItemVideoOutput hasNewPixelBufferForItemTime]**, then output it using OpenGL ES. All works perfectly if I read mp4, but if I try to read m3u8, it works for about 1 second(~30 frames), but after this period **[AVPlayerItemVideoOutput hasNewPixelBufferForItemTime]** starts returning FALSE only, so the current frame isn't updated.

In case I seek the current frame using **[AVPlayer seekToTime]** before this problem's first occur all goes normally.

Test m3u8 video I use lives here:

```
http://195.16.112.71/adaptive/3006a26a-9154-4b38-a327-4fa2a2381ae6.video/3006a26a-9154-4b38-a327-4fa2a2381ae6.m3u8
```

To reproduce this problem I modified Apple's sample AVPlayerDemo, here is it: https://yadi.sk/d/T2aVGoKnWmf5Z

The main change is in that I call **[AVPlayerDemoPlaybackViewController update]** which calls mentioned **[AVPlayerItemVideoOutput hasNewPixelBufferForItemTime]**. This function has static variable **counter** which stores the amount of successful **[AVPlayerItemVideoOutput copyPixelBufferForItemTime]** calls.

Video Url is set in **[AVPlayerDemoPlaybackViewController setURL]**, it's hardcoded in the beginning of the function. By default its value points to m3u8 video, which reproduces the problem, in this case the average value of **counter** is about 30, after the frame with that index **[AVPlayerItemVideoOutput hasNewPixelBufferForItemTime]** returns FALSE only.

In the case when other video Url is used(see beginning of **[AVPlayerDemoPlaybackViewController setURL]** - there is an alternative Url you can uncomment), all the frames are successfully read.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

Code blow does not solve my problem, I still got nothing from  `[AVPlayerItemVideoOutput hasNewPixelBufferForItemTime]`

```
if (failedCount > 100) {
    failedCount = 0;
    [_playerItem removeOutput:_output];
    [_playerItem addOutput:_output];
}
```

Finally after testing my code for a whole day. I found a way to solve it.

```
#pragma mark - AVPlayerItemOutputPullDelegate
- (void)outputMediaDataWillChange:(AVPlayerItemOutput *)sender {
    if (![self.videoOutput hasNewPixelBufferForItemTime:CMTimeMake(1, 10)]) {
        [self configVideoOutput];
    }
    [self.displayLink setPaused:NO];
}
```

Check `[AVPlayerItemVideoOutput hasNewPixelBufferForItemTime]` when `outputMediaDataWillChange:` called. **Recreate your `AVPlayerItemVideoOutput` if no new pixel buffer at 0.1s.**

Code in `[self configVideoOutput];` just recreate a new `AVPlayerItemVideoOutput` to replace current `videoOutput` property.

Why 0.1s?

I tested and experimented many times I found that first 1 or 2 frame may always get no pixel buffer. So first 1/30s, 2/30s (for video at 30fps) may have no frame and pixel buffer. But if no video pixel buffer after 0.1s, the video output may broken or something problem with it. So we need recreate it.

Comment: This worked for me. Removing and adding a new output to the AVPlayerItem seems to do the trick.

Comment: This also fixed it for me.  Big thanks, spent awhile fighting this one before I found this post.

Comment: I also had to recreate the output before adding it back to get mine to work.

Comment: I wish I could give you more than one up-vote. This solution worked for me also. Thanks, man!

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that `AVPlayerItem.status` equals `AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay` before calling `- (void)addOutput:(AVPlayerItemOutput *)output` method on `AVPlayerItem`

Reference：[Renaud's reply on this page](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/27589#thread-post-128476)

> I got the same problem with my implementation. After trying the solutions proposed here, I think I finally found the relable way to do things
>
> The `AVPlayerItemVideoOutput` must be created **AFTER** the `AVPlayerItem` status is ready to play.
>
> So
>
> 1. Create player & player item, dispatch queue and display link
> 2. Register observer for `AVPlayerItem` status key
> 3. On status `AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay`, create `AVPlayerItemVideoOutput` and start display link
>
> Thanks to all for the inspiration
>
> Renaud

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that AVPlayerItemVideoOutput "jams" somehow when using HLS multibitrate playlists. When player changes to higher bitrate -> trackid of playeritems video track changes -> it will got few pixelbuffers but after that hasNewPixelBufferForItemTime will return NO always.

I have spent days with this problem. Accidentally I noticed that if I go to background and after that back to foreground -> Video will play normally with higher bitrate. This is not the solution.

Finally I found workaround to this problem. I set counter for failed pixelbuffers, after 100 fails I remove current output from playeritem and set same instance back.

```
if (failedCount > 100)
    {
        failedCount = 0;
        [_playerItem removeOutput:_output];
        [_playerItem addOutput:_output];
    }
```

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. But I think it's better to use timer, not the counter. I found that this method can be used after 1 sec video stalling.

Comment: this worked for me, too. It's a shame that there does not seem to be an API provided way of fixing this.